# How to limit the number of collections created inside a document in firebase?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In firebase you can create a nested collection that could potentially extend a document, can this limit be set to certain limit with in security rules ?

I have this model where I want to extend the current doc with more sub collections lets say for the sake of the argument I want data-1 and data-2 as sub collections inside the doc , the issue is I want to prevent the creation of more than those 2 docs.
is this possible in security rules ?
[image: case]

```js
allow create: 
if getCreateUpdateCollection(userId)
&& request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(
['data', 'src', 'count'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit what collections can be created based on their name, by including the names of those collections in the security rules. For example:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /personal-programs/{person} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;

      match /data/Routine-1 {
        allow read, write: if <condition>;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can't otherwise restricts **how many** subcollection can be created though, as that'd require the rules engine to check the individual collections which wouldn't scale.

---

If you really want to restrict on the count of documents/subcollections, you will have to store that count in the parent document, increment/decrement it with every relevant create, and validate that operation in security rules. With those steps out of the way can you then restrict creation of new documents when the count in the parent document has reached a certain maximum.